# Half-reaction for ammonium nitrate comproportionation into dinitrogen monoxide.

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox

Ammonium nitrate comproportionates into dinitrogen monoxide in the following reaction:

> $\ce{NH4+ (aq) + NO3- (aq) -> N2O(g) + 2H2O (l)}$

I attempted to write the half-reactions by calculating the oxidation state for nitrogen in the ammonium and nitrate ions, and then finding the electrons needed for each half-reaction.

For example, for the ammonium half-reaction, I noticed that $\ce{N}$ is in a -3 oxidation state in $\ce{NH4+}$ and in a +1 oxidation state in $\ce{N2O}$. I concluded that four electrons must reduce ammonia and wrote the following preliminary equation:

> $\ce{NH4+ (aq) + 4e- -> N2O (g)}$

Which I balanced the elements using standard acidic redox into:

> $\ce{2NH4+ (aq) + H2O (l) + 4e- -> N2O(g) + 6H+ (aq)}$

However, I realized that my chemical equation is not balanced with respect to charge, indicating I have a flawed half-reaction.

**What would be the correct half-reactions for this chemical reaction?**

Comment: It is half-reaction(oxidation)$$\ce{2NH4+ (aq) + H2O (l)  -> N2O(g) + 10H+ (aq) + 8e-}$$

Comment: Ahhh. I had two mistakes: recognizing which species undergoes oxidation vs reduction and using the appropriate number of e-.